# How can I keep a running count based on a unique ID?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]I have a big data set, with a unique ID as Customer No and it might have several entries. So if a customer donates on April, his no of donations should be 1. If he was called and didn't donate in July, the the number of donations should still be 1. When the next donation occurs, then it should add up to 2. And remain two until he makes another donation. Could someone please help, am in bit of an emergency.

Comment: This isn't an emergency service site, so getting the answer you need may take a while. How is the data laid out? Are all the dates of donations in the same column?

Comment: Sorry for that, I just wanted to put it! my bad. I have updated a snap of the data file with the question now. Yup all dates of the donation are in the same function.

Comment: You should export this spreadsheet to a database and then normalize the tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wbeard52, is there a way to identify the unique id with a criteria and pull a different column value out of that row?

Comment: Please explain your data, rather than just posting a cryptic screen shot.  What values are we supposed to be looking at?  Are the actual dates relevant, or just sequence of rows?  And, for your given example data, show what you want the results to be.  And please spell out the word “number”.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my guess of what data are relevant,

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, A2, E$2:E2, ">0")
```

will count the rows, up through and including the current one,
that match the customer number on this row
and have a positive **PledgeAmount**. 
If you want to look at **<del>RecievedAmount</del> ReceivedAmount**,
change the `E`s to `F`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula, it counts all occurrences of the customer number where DM is not "no donation" and it's not empty (to avoid false counts when you add new rows).

`=COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$M$1:M2,"<>No donation",$M$1:M2,"<>"&"")`